# Converting Selenium IDE tests to run in rspec without browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec

We have a rails app and some users have used Selenium IDE firefox extension to record/create some tests. We'd like to be able to integrate these tests into our codebase of automated tests.

I understand that Selenium IDE has the ability to export test cases, but what is the easiest way to convert these tests into something that rspec can run without a browser (or headless)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used both.  Here is what you can do

- export the file using the rspec webdriver format
- adjust any use of variables or local file storage that is possible in selenium to make sense using rspec.  This will depend totally on your usage.

Here's what one goes through:

Select the test you want to export (you can also export the entire suite)
[image]
Export as rspec webdriver
[image]
Open the resulting file
[image]

Adjust as needed, e.g. move common items to spec_helper.rb and make sure it is included.

Put the file in an rspec folder, e.g. spec/views and make sure that spec_helper includes them.

Comment: Michael, can you share the Gemfile.lock and Ruby version to run this? I'm having a hard time with newer versions of everything to have the exported selenium IDE scripts running. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

> I understand that Selenium IDE has the ability to export test cases, but what is the easiest way to convert these tests into something that rspec can run without a browser (or headless)?

Selenium IDE is only plugin for Firefox. 
I believe, you can to do the same steps on another language/way. 
But for this you need to have another code.
Code for Selenium Web Driver is possible to use with headless browser as phantomJS. And its easy. 
But Selenium IDE code is only for Firefox IDE plugin.

And by the way, its hard to maintain tests written using IDE. I believe, better to rewrite all tests using Selenium WebDriver in your case. Its will be much easier and faster. (you can use Page Object model for this, as example)